# Error code "Required parameter missing: billing_address" when trying to link my debit card to my coinbase account

Tags: php, error-handling, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I have filled in all the fields correctly when linking my card, however, there isn't even a parameter for a billing address, so how could this be missing? ([pic of the fields and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn3wl.png)) My account is already previously set up with my billing address, and I have also linked my account with this card before with no issues.

Comment: And now you are hoping a coinbase support employee is reading this?

Comment: I was wondering if anyone was experiencing a similar issue, I've already contacted support and they've been of no help, only stating that I need to re-format my address, although my address is properly formatted and has worked with this debit card in the past.